# Firebase storage is uploading image as 9B file

Tags: javascript, firebase, expo, firebase-storage

[image]

I am working on a program to upload image. I am using "expo-image-picker" to pick the image and it is correctly updating the "image" state as we can see below. Code executes and image file gets uploaded in Firebase storage but its uploaded as 9 bytes file and not as full 2.4 mb image.

Please help me understand the mistake that I am making.

---

image value:
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/15A92FD5-894C-47D6-ABEF-36F73CA7F778/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fapp26Apr-a5cceae1-72c0-4cec-a926-ffb46822d087/ImagePicker/C7ABC0E1-80FC-4B87-A1AD-8B6DD4A1BB9A.jpg

uploadUri value:
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/15A92FD5-894C-47D6-ABEF-36F73CA7F778/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Fapp26Apr-a5cceae1-72c0-4cec-a926-ffb46822d087/ImagePicker/C7ABC0E1-80FC-4B87-A1AD-8B6DD4A1BB9A.jpg

filename value:
C7ABC0E1-80FC-4B87-A1AD-8B6DD4A1BB9A.jpg

---

```
const uri = image;
const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
const uploadUri = Platform.OS === "ios" ? uri.replace("file://", "") : uri;

firebase
  .storage()
  .ref(filename)
  .put(uploadUri)
  .then((value) => {
    console.log("Image uploaded");
  });
```

Comment: I also noticed that actual image filename on mobile phone is different. I am suspecting if Firebase Storage is not able to interpret the Uri generated by expo. So, Firebase is still uploading the provided filename but it is not able to upload actual file which does not exist in the provided path. I am using latest version of expo-image-picker.

  "expo-image-picker": "^10.1.4",

Answer (score 3):

I could find the solution of using blob to save the image. Sharing it below in case anyone faces same issue.

```
let uri = image;
const filename = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
const uploadUri = Platform.OS === "ios" ? uri.replace("file://", "") : uri;

const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onload = function () {
    resolve(xhr.response);
  };
  xhr.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    reject(new TypeError("Network request failed"));
  };
  xhr.responseType = "blob";
  xhr.open("GET", uri, true);
  xhr.send(null);
});

firebase
  .storage()
  .ref()
  .child("user/" + userid)
  .put(blob)
  .then((uri) => {
    console.log(uri);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: I spent almost 3 Hours on this. I really dont know why Firebase Cloud Storage would only work with the Blob Hack. Yet their documentation says File/Blob. Thank you though. :)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and found the solution after a couple of hours. You have to convert your image to a file/blob format and put it on **put()**.

The solution is like below code :

```
fetch(filePath)
  .then(response => {
    return response.blob();
  })
  .then(blob => {
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref().child('test.png');
    storageRef.put(blob).then(snapshot => {
      console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
    });
  });
```

Comment: in this instance what would "filepath" be?